# UPS returns blank rate

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ups

I have configured UPS method in my Magento site.

The problem is that when i am using below mentioned Address as origin : 
Country : United State

Region/State : California

Zip/Postal Code : 90034

And in destination :

Country : United State

Region/State : California

Zip/Postal Code : 94301

Its return proper rates.

But when i below mentioned address as origin

Country : Canada

Region/State : Ontario

Zip/Postal Code : L6R2E7

and in Destination

Country : United State

Region/State : California

Zip/Postal Code : 94301

Its return all shipping method with 0 values.

If any one faced this problem kindly help me.
Your helps are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug.

Go to that shipping method and enable debug mode.

After enable, go to cart page and click on Estimate Rate.

Now go to ftp  var/log/, check log file, you will got more idea what is your error.